# javascript, compare arrays of different sizes

Tags: javascript, arrays

with two arrays of potentially different sizes, what is best way to see if they are the same *as far as it goes*

for example

```
var a1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var a2 = [ 1, 2 ];
var a3 = [ 1, 3 ];

a1 == a2 => true;
a1 == a3 => false;
```

am positive this has been done thousands of times and the syntax is well memorized

Comment: Why is the first true and the second false?

Comment: why `al` & `a2` are same?? because `a2` content is there in `a1`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function compareArraySeq(a, b) {
    return a.slice(0, b.length).join(' ') == b.slice(0, a.length).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: outstanding!!  do not need function call!  typing overhead not too bad.

Comment: @ccyoung This fails for empty string array elements, you should not use it.

Comment: @Tomalak - tested correctly with empty arrays - missing what you're saying - can you give example?  thanks

Comment: @Tomalak - Excellent point. This will definitely fail in that case. It is possible to work around that with join(' '). Changed that in the answer.

Comment: @ccyoung `['a,', '', 'z'].join() == ['a', ',', 'z'].join() // true` My mistake was to think that `join()` was the same as `join('')`, but nevertheless it can fail for array elements that contain a comma. And of course for all array elements that cannot be converted to string unambiguously (think `'[object Object]'`). Therefore `[{a:1}].join() == [{b:2}].join()`. Just don't use it, this *smart* shortcut solution is incorrect.

Comment: @bebraw No, it isn't. Whatever delimiter you use, when the array elements contain it your solution *will* break.

Comment: @Tomalak Gotcha. So better use some other solution if one needs to compare something other than lists of numbers. :)

Comment: @bebraw And even lists of numbers will fail if the delimiter is a `.`, an `e`, a `+`, a `-` or a digit.

Comment: @Tomalak D'oh. What a can of worms! :)

Comment: yes, under some conditions can fail, so correct in that this is not a 100% solution.  but, when the stars are aligned, a quite nice shortcut.

Comment: @ccyoung "When the stars are aligned" is a doomed way of programming.

Answer (score 4):

What about this (I'll just demonstrate on a1 and a2 -> I presume you can make function out of this):

```
var min_val = min(a1.length, a2.length);
var equals = true;

for(i = 0; i < min_val; i++)
{
    if(a1[i] != a2[i])
    {
        equals = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

The result will be in equals variable of course. If you want to make function out of this, just pass a1 and a2 as arguments and return equals.

Comment: true, that solves it, but thought that with slice etc could get it done without creating a function

Comment: Unlike the slice solution, this also works with non-scalar values, i.e. arrays of objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
function compareArraySeq(a1, a2) {
  var i, l = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length); 

  for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[**edit**] based on [Tomalaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) comments I'd say JSON can come to the rescue.

So, again: here's an Array extension that does what [I suppose] you want to do:

```
function comparePartial(arr1,arr2){
  var arr2 = this, l1 = arr1.length, l2 = arr2.length;

  return ( l1<1 || l2<1
            ? false :
              JSON.stringify(arr1.slice(0, l2)) ===
              JSON.stringify(arr2.slice(0, l1))
         );
}
Array.prototype.comparePartial = 
    Array.prototype.comparePartial || comparePartial;

//usage
    var a1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
   ,a2 = [ 1, 2 ]
   ,a3 = [ 1, 3 ]
   ,a4 = ['','']
   ,a5 = ['','','']
   ,a6 = []
   ,a7 = ['bla','doh',1]
   ,a8 = ['bla','doh',1,'yeah','really']
   ,a9 = [1,3,5,'doh']
   ,a10= ['1','3','5','doh']
   ,a11= [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}]
   ,a12= [{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4},{e:5,f:6}]

console.log(
  [ a1.comparePartial(a2)
   ,a2.comparePartial(a1)
   ,a1.comparePartial(a3)
   ,a4.comparePartial(a5)
   ,a5.comparePartial(a6)
   ,a1.comparePartial(a6)
   ,a8.comparePartial(a7)
   ,a10.comparePartial(a9)  //=> 'type safe' comparison
   ,a11.comparePartial(a12) //=> can compare arrays of Objects
  ].join(' - ')
); //=> true - true - false - true - false - false - true - false - true
```

Comment: pretty clever.  _could_ use this approach without the function def, but _way_ too much typing.

Comment: May be the Array extension is an idea then?

Comment: @KooiInc See my comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9248739/18771). Converting the array to String does not cut it.

Comment: @Tomalak: yep. Replaced my answer with a JSON variant of the comparison

Comment: @KooiInc Probably not overly efficient, but in exchange its simple and works for nested data. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
function prefixEqual(a, b) {
    var prefixLength = a.length < b.length ? a.length : b.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < prefixLength; i+=1)
        if( a[i] != b[i] )
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop checking one spot at a time.
I have made this:

```
var compare = function (a1, a2) {
    var l = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can compare arrays like this:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var b = [0, 1, 2];
var c = [0, 1, 3];

compare(a, b); //true
compare(a, c); //false
```

Hope this works for you :)

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8zbJj/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are strings or numbers or booleans you can compare their String values.

```
function compareSimpleValues(a,b){
  if(a.length>=b.length)return String(a).indexOf(String(b))===0;
  return String(b).indexOf(String(a))===0;
}
```